# How can I track down which property in my code first model maps to a particular column?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a code first entity framework project with an entity Staff which has a number of self-referential navigation properties of type Staff.

In the database schema I can see that there is a column created named Staff_Id which is not the primary key for the table and in all current records is always null.

I cannot figure out what this column is actually being used for and as it seems to be unused I'd like to remove it. However I cannot find any means of identifying why entity framework is generating this column in the first place.

Does anyone know how I can track down which property in my model is causing entity framework to generate this column?

Comment: Inspect ALL of your model classes and their relationships. I would suspect that `Staff_Id` is being auto generated by a foreign key defined somewhere in your model.

Comment: According to the database it's a foreign key referencing the same table it's defined in. I've removed all properties of type ICollection<Staff> from the Staff entity and yet that column is still there. What external entity could cause Staff to reference itself?

Comment: I've found the property responsible in the end but I'm leaving this question open in the hopes that someone knows of a more automated way of mapping columns back to properties.

Comment: Agreed. Might I also suggest that you reveal a bit more info about the problem/project...such as revealing the model classes themselves and how exactly you found the "property responsible". This may help solicit the answer you are looking for.